# An expansion of the product of functions in Fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let 
$$f(x)=a^{(1)}_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{(1)}_n\cos(nx)+b^{(1)}_n\sin(nx)    ~~~(1)$$ and
$$g(x)=a^{(2)}_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{(2)}_n\cos(nx)+b^{(2)}_n\sin(nx)~~~  (2) $$,
 where the conditions 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}| a^{(1)}_n|+ |b^{(1)}_n|<+\infty,$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}| a^{(2)}_n|+ |b^{(2)}_n|<+\infty$$
hold true and  $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$.
Find the Fourier trigonometric series
$$a^{(3)}_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{(3)}_n\cos(nx)+b^{(3)}_n\sin(nx)$$

of the product $f\times g$ on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ by using (1)-(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions are complicated. For instance
$$\begin{align}
a_0^{(3)}&=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Bigl(\frac{a_0^{(1)}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{(1)}_n\cos(nx)+b^{(1)}_n\sin(nx)\,\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{a_0^{(2)}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{(2)}_n\cos(nx)+b^{(2)}_n\sin(nx)\Bigr)\,dx\\
&=\frac{a_0^{(1)}a_0^{(2)}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigl(a_n^{(1)}a_n^{(2)}+b_n^{(1)}b_n^{(2)}\bigr).
\end{align}$$
The interchange of integration and summation is justified by the absolute suability of the coefficients.

The computations will be easier if you rewrite the series as complex Fourier series:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_k^{(1)}e^{ikx},\quad g(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_k^{(2)}e^{ikx}.
$$
Then
$$
f(x)\,g(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\Bigl(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}c_j^{(1)}c_{k-j}^{(2)}\Bigr)e^{ikx}.
$$

Comment: @  Julian Aguirre    It is very nice!  Thank you very much

Comment: If the answer was useful, could you please up vote it?